# Can you identify this large sword?

Tags: part-identification

I thought it was something in the bionicle set, but I can't find it on bricklink. Anyone know what this is?

[image: large red sword]

Comment: How did you know it was a sword, rather than a wing or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually originally a Hero Factory piece.

[11338 - Hero Factory Weapon - Axe/Sword with Jagged Blade](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11338)

[image]

A red one is exclusive to [70203 - CHI Cragger](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70203-1).

[image]